# Какой будет путь у сохраняемого файла?

Tags: c#

На msdn нашел такой пример:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt",
"This is new text to be added.", False)
```

Если вместо полного пути указать "test.txt" - ошибки нет, файл куда-то сохраняется. Вопрос, какой полный путь и есть ли правило формирования пути при указании только имени файла?

Comment: *какой полный путь и есть ли правило формирования пути при указании только имени файла?* Текущий путь на текущем устройстве. См. My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory Вероятно, это текущий каталог запуска программы, но не факт...

Comment: Файл будет сохраняться в каталоге программы, в папке Debug/Release. Допустим, папка находится на рабочем столе, то путь будет `C:\Users\user\Desktop\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\ваш_файл`

Comment: @dmepty вовсе не обязательно

Comment: Такой вопрос, у пользователей не всегда есть доступ для доступа к папке,в которой установлена программа. Выходит, для безопасности, путь стоит указывать полностью?

Comment: В папке с исполняемым файлом должен находится

Comment: Pavel Mayorov, уверен у вас есть что добавить к комментариям. Если не сложно, поделитесь знаниями

Comment: @АлександрПузанов А куда вы хотите сохранить файл?

Comment: ProgramData, к примеру

Comment: Путь к ProgramData string str = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);

Comment: У вас путь в коде неправильно указан - слеши не экранированы

Comment: Перед путем добавьте символ "@". Аля `@"C:\ProgramData\text.txt"`

Comment: ))) Ну я же не настолько глуп

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если указано только имя файла - файл будет создан в текущем каталоге.

Текущий каталог может быть любым.

Студия при запуске приложениея выставляет в качестве текущего каталога тот, в котором лежат бинарники.

При запуске из-под командной строки - текущим каталогов будет тот,  в котором пользователь находился в командной строке.

При запуске из-под чего-то другого - текущий каталог выставляется полностью на усмотрение создателей этого "другого".

Если хотите получить файл в конкретном каталоге - задавайте полный путь.

Comment: *Если указано только имя файла - файл будет создан в текущем каталоге.* Добавьте - текущего диска. Он ведь тоже может быть любым из существующих, и в любое время может быть изменён.